# Nethermind x Prysm Snap Sync Takes Long Time

Tags: prysm, nethermind

I am trying to run an Ethereum node using Nethermind execution client and Prysm consensus client in Windows. After some time the execution client reaches 100% but when I try to get the current block it returns 0. Even the health UI it says the node is healthy but still syncing. How long will it take to fully sync? It's almost 2 days now. I'm using snap sync.

Chain: Ethereum mainnet

Followings are the commands used to run Nethermind and Prysm.

nethermind --JsonRpc.Enabled true --HealthChecks.Enabled true --HealthChecks.UIEnabled true --JsonRpc.JwtSecretFile=../consensus/jwt.hex --datadir D:/ethereum/data

prysm.bat beacon-chain --checkpoint-sync-url=https://beaconstate.info --execution-endpoint=http://localhost:8551 --jwt-secret=jwt.hex --datadir D:/ethereum/data --checkpoint-sync-url="https://beaconstate.ethstaker.cc/" --genesis-beacon-api-url="https://beaconstate.ethstaker.cc/"

enter image description here

I have tried using different execution and consensus clients already. I'm expecting to query Ethereum blockchain using my own node.